# Remove percent sign and convert values to integer of CSV file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Host;Service;OK;WARN;CRIT;UNKNOWN;Flapping;H.Down;Downtime;N/A
Server1;DNS;0.00%;0.00%;100.00%;0.00%;0.00%;0.00%;0.00%;0.00%
Server2;Filesystem C:/;0.00%;0.00%;100.00%;0.00%;0.00%;0.00%;0.00%;0.00%
Server2;Filesystem D:/;28.82%;0.00%;70.68%;0.00%;0.00%;0.50%;0.00%;0.00%
Server3;Events;0.00%;0.00%;98.97%;0.00%;0.00%;1.03%;0.00%;0.00%
Server4;W32Time;0.00%;0.00%;100.00%;0.00%;0.00%;0.00%;0.00%;0.00%
```

I'm currently importing it with

```bsh
$computers = Import-Csv .\foo.csv -Delimiter ";"
```

I've been trying a couple of different things to try and clear out the percent sign to no avail.

Ultimately, I'd like to get each of the values as numbers to which I can then format them so that any value above 0 (or 0.0%) gets formatted with a color. I figure that the CSV import is importing everything as a string, so it would be more difficult to math around a string, and even more so with a string with a special character in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One obvious thing to do is to pre-process your data file to remove the `%` signs.  For example:

```
(Get-Content .\data.csv).Replace("%","") | 
    Out-File .\data2.csv -Append
```

Once this is done, it is easy to use maths on the 'numbers' by casting them to a numerical type, which you'd need to do for any CSV (since, as you say, PowerShell treats everything as a string in that case).  For example:

```
Import-Csv .\data2.csv -Delimiter ";" |
    ForEach-Object {
        switch([double]$_.CRIT)
        {
            {$_ -lt 75.0} {"CRIT is under 75: $_"}
            default {"CRIT is over 75: $_"}
        }
    }
```

**EDIT: Compact version incorporating @LotPings suggestion:**

```
(Get-Content .\data.csv).Replace("%","")  |
        ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ";" |
            ForEach-Object {
                switch([double]$_.CRIT)
                {
                    {$_ -lt 75.0} {"CRIT is under 75: $_"}
                    default {"CRIT is over 75: $_"}
                }
        }
```

Comment: No intermediate file neccessary when using `(Get-Content .\data.csv).Replace("%","") |ConvertFrom-Csv -delimiter ';'`

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding in reading the data, each line indicates the time in percent of the last 24 hours the service in question on the server has spend in that particular state. So in my example, the DNS Service on Server1 has spend 100% of the last 24 hours in a critical state, and the D:\ drive on Server2 has spent 28.82% of the last 24 hours in OK, 70.68% in WARN and 0.50% in H.Down status.

So I'll have to do a ForEach-Object switch for all of the columns to format anything > 0

Thanks